# I get the warnning "recipe for target 'swmod2.o' failed//[swmod2.o] Error 1" when i compile FVCOM

Tags: compiler-errors

I face a strange problem when I compile FVCOM4.0，which was used many time.

[image: 1]

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Comment: mpif90  -c  -O3 -I/home/yz/FVCOM3dimension/FVCOM4.0/FVCOM_source/libs/install/include        swmod2.f90
swmod2.f90(117): error #7844: Invalid directive.
!$OMP&              KM_WAM, KM01, SIGM_10, SIGM01)
^
compilation aborted for swmod2.f90 (code 1)
makefile:42: recipe for target 'swmod2.o' failed
make: *** [swmod2.o] Error 1
root@ecs-40ad:/home/yz/FVCOM3dimension/FVCOM4.0/FVCOM_source#

Comment: I am so sorry. It's my first time use stack so I could make some mistake

Comment: Post in question, not comment.